# Non-desired "int to tuple" conversion when adding key/value in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, type-conversion, variable-assignment, tweepy

I'm using tweepy to crawl tweets and I want to format the data for my data warehouse.

The following method is called each time a tweet is received:

```
def on_status(self, status):
    statusAsDict= {
        "text": status.text,
        "created_at": status.created_at,
        "language": status.lang,
        "user": {
            "id": status.author.id,
            "name": status.author.name,
            "screen_name": status.author.screen_name,
            "verified": status.author.verified,
            "favourites_count": status.author.favourites_count,
            "followers_count": status.author.followers_count,
            "friends_count": status.author.friends_count
        }
    }

    if status.in_reply_to_status_id != None:
        statusAsDict["in_reply_to_status_id"] = status.in_reply_to_status_id,

    if status.in_reply_to_screen_name != None:
        statusAsDict["in_reply_to_screen_name"] = status.in_reply_to_screen_name,

    if status.coordinates != None:
        statusAsDict["coordinates"] = status.coordinates,

    if hasattr(status, "retweeted_status"):
        statusAsDict["retweet"] = {}
        statusAsDict["retweet"]["id"] = status.retweeted_status.id,
        statusAsDict["retweet"]["user_id"] = status.retweeted_status.author.id,
        statusAsDict["retweet"]["user_screen_name"] = status.retweeted_status.author.screen_name,
        statusAsDict["retweet"]["user_verified"] = status.retweeted_status.author.verified,
        statusAsDict["retweet"]["user_favourites_count"] = status.retweeted_status.author.favourites_count,
        statusAsDict["retweet"]["user_followers_count"] = status.retweeted_status.author.followers_count,
        statusAsDict["retweet"]["user_friends_count"] = status.retweeted_status.author.friends_count,
        statusAsDict["retweet"]["retweet_count"] = status.retweeted_status.retweet_count,
        statusAsDict["retweet"]["text"] = status.retweeted_status.text,

    if status.in_reply_to_status_id != None:
        print type(status.in_reply_to_status_id)
        print type(statusAsDict["in_reply_to_status_id"])
        print statusAsDict
```

It prints the following statements:

```
<type 'int'>
<type 'tuple'>
{'language': u'en', 'text': u'@fuckitslrhafi7 @fuckitslrhafi rt this from ff and main acc for 50 https://....', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 30, 12, 25, 10), 'in_reply_to_status_id': (715149454257442816,), 'in_reply_to_screen_name': (u'fuckitslrhafi7',), 'user': {'favourites_count': 55, 'screen_name': u'JOlNTZOUlS', 'friends_count': 29, 'followers_count': 16, 'verified': False, 'id': 3040734513, 'name': u'accs in bio'}}
```

It should be

```
'in_reply_to_status_id': 715149454257442816
```

not

```
'in_reply_to_status_id': (715149454257442816,)
```

How to avoid the conversion from int to tuple ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra trailing comma:

```
    statusAsDict["in_reply_to_status_id"] = status.in_reply_to_status_id,
```

Remove the trailing comma and it should work.  For example,`1,` is a tuple `(1,)`, whereas `1` is just an `int`.

You might also want to try using the `vars` function to convert `status` into a `dict`, e.g.

```
statusAsDict = vars(status)
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing back my sanity.
In my case, I was mapping one dict to another, assigning each value following a json pattern, with comma after each key-value pair, but then I decided to assign each key-value pair in different lines but forgot the comma.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the trailing comma on the line where you assign it.

`statusAsDict["in_reply_to_status_id"] = status.in_reply_to_status_id`

Commas are what define a tuple, not parenthesis, so `(1)` is still an integer, and `1,` is a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, remove the comma in the statement:

```
statusAsDict['in_reply_to_status_id'] = status.in_reply_to_status_id,
```